# Setting/getting the class properties by string name

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

What I'm trying to do is setting the value of the property in a class using a string.  For example, my class has the following properties:

```
myClass.Name
myClass.Address
myClass.PhoneNumber
myClass.FaxNumber
```

All the fields are of `string` type so I know ahead of time that it's always a string.  Now, I want to be able to set the properties using a string as you could do with a `DataSet` object.  Something like this:

```
myClass["Name"] = "John"
myClass["Address"] = "1112 River St., Boulder, CO"
```

Ideally, I want to just assign a variable and then set the property using that string name from the variable:

```
string propName = "Name"
myClass[propName] = "John"
```

I was reading about reflection and maybe it's the way to do it but I'm not sure how to go about setting that up while keeping the property access intact in the class.  I want to still be able to use:

```
myClass.Name = "John"
```

Any code examples would be really great.

Comment: Look at that too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279374/how-do-i-use-net-reflection-to-search-for-a-property-by-name-ignoring-case

Comment: I'm trying to do this because I'm getting the data dump from the data base and I'm only selectively wanting to pick out the fields I need to store in my class.  Basically I don't want to do a check for each item and store in the class.  I need to loop through all the fields and only pick out and add the item to the class dynamically.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp/24919811#24919811

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can add indexer property, a *pseudocode*:

```
public class MyClass 
{
     public object this[string propertyName] 
     {
        get
        {
           // probably faster without reflection:
           // like:  return Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyValues[propertyName] 
           // instead of the following
           Type myType = typeof(MyClass);                   
           PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
           return myPropInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        }
        set
        {
           Type myType = typeof(MyClass);                   
           PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
           myPropInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You, my friend, are an absolute genius! Thank you!

Comment: Nice! I would suggest replacing `typeof(MyClass)` with just `GetType()` to make it more generic, if it is used in abstract class for an example. :)

Comment: Nice solution! But won't work with properties as Dictionary type, Visual Studio points error when trying to add a value - no definition for Add. Thought is limited to set the value, so there is a workaround that is creating a temporary dictionary 'D' and set de value as 'D'.

Comment: Is there something similar for `static` classes?

Answer (score 6):

You can add an indexer to your class and use reflection to aces the properties:

```
using System.Reflection;

public class MyClass {

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            var properties = typeof(MyClass)
                    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (property.Name == name && property.CanRead)
                    return property.GetValue(this, null);
            }

            throw new ArgumentException("Can't find property");

        }
        set {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

May be something like this?

```
    public class PropertyExample
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _properties;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _properties["FirstName"]; }
        set { _properties["FirstName"] = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _properties["LastName"]; }
        set { _properties["LastName"] = value; }
    }
    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return _properties[propertyName]; }
        set { _properties[propertyName] = value; }
    }

    public PropertyExample()
    {
        _properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```