# pass property/fieldname to predicate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, lambda, predicate

Forgive me, I'm not entirely sure my question is worded correctly. 
I'm creating a search component where the user can search different fields with different operators... e.g. description.contains(keywords) and measurement.startsWith(yards).....

So here is what I have:

```
void SearchDescription(IQueryable<MyClass> results, string keywords)
{
    switch(operator)
    { 
        case "Contains":
            results=results.Where(ele => ele.description.Contains(keywords));
            break;
        case "StartsWith":
            results = results.Where(ele => ele.description.StartsWith(keywords));
            break;
        ... and so on.....
    }
}
```

Currently I have a method just as above for each field.... SearchDescription(), SearchID(), SearchMeasure(), etc. The only difference being the field/property name.

**UPDATE**

Upon further research possibly something like:

```
void Search(IQueryable<Entity> results, string keywords, Expression<Func<Entity>,object>> predicate)
{
    results = results.Where(ele => predicate.Contains(keywords));
}
```

which could be called like:

```
Search(results, "my search terms", ele => ele.description);
```

This obviously doesn't work in it's current form, but maybe that is a clearer description of what I am after.

Thanks for all the responses so far.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10283288/1300049. Or you can define few actions to get needed properties and pass them (Actions) to your Search method

Comment: You might look at some of the Dynamic Linq options out there. Some use reflection and some build expression trees on the fly. It's not as straight-forward as you're hoping though, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by implementing a `Compose` method that will take two expressions and return an expression that acts as if it would invoke the first, then provide that as the parameter to the second:

```
void Search(IQueryable<Entity> results, string keywords,
    Expression<Func<Entity, string>> selector)
{
    results = results.Where(selector.Compose(obj => obj.Contains(keywords)));
}
```

To implement that we'll start off with a helper method that allows us to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}

public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
```

Using that tool it's as simple as a handful of replacements stuffed back together into a lambda:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

It also seems odd to filter the query to items where a single string with all of the words is contained in the given field.  It seems more likely that you want to get items that contain *any* of a list of strings.  That's different, and requires just a touch more work.

We can use a new class we'll call a `PredicateBuilder` to build up a filter that takes the logical `OR` of a bunch of other filters.

```
void Search(IQueryable<Entity> results, IEnumerable<string> keywords,
    Expression<Func<Entity, string>> selector)
{
    var finalFilter = keywords.Aggregate(
        PredicateBuilder.False<Entity>(),
        (filter, keyword) => filter.Or(
            selector.Compose(obj => obj.Contains(keyword))));
    results = results.Where(finalFilter);
}
```

We can implement this class using the `Replace` method defined earlier like so:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(
        this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var secondBody = expr2.Body.Replace(expr2.Parameters[0], expr1.Parameters[0]);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, secondBody), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(
        this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var secondBody = expr2.Body.Replace(expr2.Parameters[0], expr1.Parameters[0]);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, secondBody), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Reflection to retrieve a PropertyInfo using the name of the wanted property. Note that Reflection is a bit slow and if used many times in a second, it can seriously slow your program down.

```
void Search(IQueryable<MyClass> results, string keywords, string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo elePropInfo = ele.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    string elePropValue = (string)elePropInfo.GetValue(ele, null); // the second argument should be null for non-indexed properties
    switch(operator)
    { 
        case "Contains":
            results = results.Where(ele => elePropValue.Contains(keywords));
            break;
        case "StartsWith":
            results = results.Where(ele => elePropValue.StartsWith(keywords));
            break;
        // etc
    }
}
```

More info on `GetProperty()` can be found here in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is there a way I could do this so that the property name would still be strongly typed instead of a string?

Comment: @Matt I'm not sure but I don't think so.

Comment: @Matt Make sure that PropertyName is exactly the same as the property in ele.

Comment: You're trying to get the type and value of a variable that doesn't exist in that scope.