# How to set value of a property that is a class in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, set

I am trying to set the value of a property that is a class.

```
protected bool TryUpdate(PropertyInfo prop, object value)
{
    try
    {
        prop.SetValue(this, value);

        // If not set probably a complex type
        if (value != prop.GetValue(this))
        {
           //... Don't know what to do
        }
        // If still not set update failed
        if (value != prop.GetValue(this))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

}

I'm calling this method on a number of properties from a variety of classes. This issue is when I have a class like the following:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }

    public IComplexObject Object { get; set; }
}
```

Name and Number are set just fine, but if I try and set an instance of a class that inherits from IComplexObject on Object there is no errors it just remains null.

Is there an easy way to set an instance of a class as property?

So for example if I pass in prop as {IComplexObject Object} and object as

```
var object = (object) new ComplexObject
{
    prop1 = "Property"
    prop2 = "OtherProperty"
}
```

At the end there are no errors but Object remains null and is not set to the instance of ComplexObject. It needs to be generic so I can pass in any class and the property will be updated.

Comment: Assuming the example doesn't generate any exceptions when setting the `Object` property, then the set should have been successful. Perhaps the equality comparison for your `IComplexObject`s is what's misbehaving? Step-through debugging can be helpful here. If it is the equality, then you could try replacing the comparison with `ReferenceEquals` for starters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283206/c-sharp-setting-getting-the-class-properties-by-string-name

Comment: Why is your update method async? It doesn't seem to use a task.

Comment: Post a short but complete, resproducable code...

Comment: Updated the code and question to be more clear. My issue is SetValue isn't setting Object it just remains null without any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is needlessly complicated, but it works completely fine.  I've taken your code and expanded it into a complete example that runs.

The output is this.

```
Name: asdf, Number: A1B2, Object: hello this is complexobject
It was not null
```

This shows that the `Object` property is no different from any of the others.  "Complex object" is not a term that really means anything in .net.  Additionally your use of `async` seems unnecessary and confusing.

```
async void Main() {
    Test t = new Test();
    Type type = typeof(Test);

    await t.TryUpdate(type.GetProperty(nameof(t.Name)), "asdf");
    await t.TryUpdate(type.GetProperty(nameof(t.Number)), "A1B2");
    await t.TryUpdate(type.GetProperty(nameof(t.Object)), (object)new ComplexObject());

    Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());

    PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(nameof(t.Object));

    if (prop.GetValue(t) == null) {
        Console.WriteLine("It was null");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("It was not null");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public IComplexObject Object { get; set; }

    // Added for the purpose if showing contents
    public override string ToString() => $"Name: {Name}, Number: {Number}, Object: {Object}";

    // Why is this async?  Your code does not await
    public async Task<bool> TryUpdate(PropertyInfo prop, object value) {
        await Task.Delay(0); // Added to satisfy async
        try {
            prop.SetValue(this, value);

            // If not set probably a complex type
            if (value != prop.GetValue(this)) {
                //... Don't know what to do
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

public interface IComplexObject { }
class ComplexObject : IComplexObject {
    public override string ToString() => "hello this is complexobject";
}
```

Comment: Updated the code and question to be more clear. My issue is SetValue isn't setting Object it just remains null without any exceptions. What I am looking for is what to put into the if statement to set Object since set Value doesn't work.

Comment: Your question is still not clear.  The code in my example shows that setting `Object` *does* work.  The property is set to the instance of `ComplexObject`, and is no longer null.

Comment: Then I'm just confused this doesn't work for me. If it was :

if (prop.GetValue(this) == null) {
 return false
            }
which would mean that the value wasn't set mine returns false.

Comment: I added some code to my example that does `if (prop.GetValue(this) == null)`, and it correctly shows that the value was set and is no longer null.  The code works, and I can't reproduce the problem based on your code.  In fact, the code in my example shows the opposite.  Please include enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This example works. I've put it for a reference.
I've changed it to await the task and extract the return value to the result variable so you could see that it returns true.

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }

    public IComplexObject Object { get; set; }

    public async Task<bool> TryUpdate(PropertyInfo prop, object value) {
        try {
            prop.SetValue(this, value);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception) {

        }

        return false;
    }

}

public class ComplexObject : IComplexObject
{
}

public interface IComplexObject
{

}
static class  Program
{

    static void Main() {
        TestMethod();
    }

    static async void TestMethod() {
        var test = new Test();
        var result = await test.TryUpdate(test.GetType().GetProperty("Object"), new ComplexObject());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code returns Object as null for me.  My code returns false without any errors.