# How to 'select' object field when you only have a string with exact name as the object field

Tags: c#, .net

Sorry if the title is not clear, it was hard to properly word this question.

I have an object named Stuff and MoreStuff.

```
public class Stuff()
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
}

public class MoreStuff()
{
    public string Field3;
    public string Field4;
}
```

I want to create something that adds a value to Field1 when the string fieldValue = 'Field1'

To make it more clear, something like this. But I want to have it generic for any object.:

```
string fieldValue = 'Field1'
Stuff thing = new Stuff();
checkField(fieldValue);
thing.fieldValue = 'checked';

string fieldValue = 'Field4'
MoreStuff moreThing = new MoreStuff();
checkField(fieldValue);
moreThing.fieldValue = 'checked';
```

Is this possible to do in C#? I can't find anything about it, also hard to search for a question like this.

Comment: Use reflection, but this sounds like it may be an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You can use reflection to get the value of a field by name, however you can't just aribitrarily add fields to the object. You could do that with an ExpandoObject but not plain classes, at least not without IL weaving.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# setting/getting the class properties by string name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283206/c-sharp-setting-getting-the-class-properties-by-string-name)

Comment: Thanks, reflection was exactly what I was looking for. The adding of fields was just a bad example of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
string fieldName = "Field1";
Stuff thing = new Stuff();

thing.GetType().GetField(fieldName).SetValue(thing, "checked");
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about reflection.

Answer (score 1):

```
Square test = new Square();
test.Field1 = "sdflsjf";
test.Field2 = "sdlfksj";
test.Field3 = "sldfjs";

foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in test.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (propertyInfo.Name == "Field2")
        propertyInfo.SetValue(test, "checked");

}
```

This uses System.Reflection to do approximately what you're looking for by the sounds of it.