# How to use a variable to access an object member in c#

Tags: c#, object

I have a web service that returns a custom object (a struct type) `APIStruct user`.
I have a variable holding the name of the current field it is checking for `currentField`.

Now, in a situation where `user` contains `first_name` and `last_name`, I can access the value using `user.first_name` or `user.last_name`. BUT, is it possible to hold the field name in a variable and access the value through the variable? working like:

```
var currentField = "first_name";
var value = user.currentField;
```

Obviously the above is not working, so is there any way to do this? In the past with languages such as PowerShell it works just like above `$currentField = "first_name"; $value = user.$currentField`

I've tried `user.currentField` `user.(currentField)` `user[currentField]` `user.$currentField`

Comment: Yes this is possible. Please do a little research before asking a question that's been  asked by many others :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283206/c-sharp-setting-getting-the-class-properties-by-string-name

Comment: I did do research and couldn't find the answer. Just because the question exist somewhere here doesn't mean I used the exact terminology they did to come across it in my search. I searched what I could and nothing came back properly answering my question. So next time, please offer helpful advice or a simple link to the other questing and mark as duplicate instead of criticism and shaming with assumptions that no research was done.

Comment: I did provide a link to the answer in question. I literally searched "how to access class property by string value" and it was the first result. I wasn't shaming or criticizing either, I'm sorry you took it that way.

Comment: You can also copy and paste the title to your question into google and see that the first result is also an answer to your question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx). Create a method like this:

```
public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

and call it:

```
string currentField = "first_name";
GetPropValue(user, currentField);
```

But it must be said, it is not the way you should use for the standard reading of object values.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your object class to support access to a `Dictionary` of additional properties, accessible through an [explicit indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287928/how-do-i-overload-the-square-bracket-operator-in-c).

```
public class myClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> Something = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public object this[string i]
    {
        get { return Something[i]; }
        set { Something[i] = value; }
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
    myClass m = new myClass();
```

Set value:

```
    m["fist name"] = "Name";
    m["level"] = 2;
    m["birthday"] = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
```

Get value:

```
    int level = (int)m["level"];
    string firstName = (string)m["first name"];
    DateTime dt = (DateTime)m["birthday"];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for called Reflection.

```
var type = user.GetType(); // Get type object
var property = type.GetProperty(currentField); // get property info object
var value = property.GetValue(user); // get value from object.
```

Be careful - reflection is pretty slow compared to direct property access.

Comment: You were faster, Oleh :)

Comment: `type.GetProperty(currentField)` , not `user.GetProperty(currentField)`

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfect for me.

Answer (score -2):

Another option you may have is to use a switch statement.  Something like:

```
switch (currentField){
    case "first_name":
            value = user.first_name;
            break;
    case "last_name":
            value = user.last_name;
            break;
```

etc...

Comment: eh... this is not what he wants.