# vb object attribute as variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a vb or c# question (I'm doing it in vb but either way is fine)
so I am going through this big case statement that is like this........

```vb
Select Case item("itemLabelType")
    Case "Shelf1"
        oItemLabel.Shelf1 = item("value")
    Case "Exp1"
        oItemLabel.Exp1 = item("Exp1")
    Case "CureDt1"
        oItemLabel.CureDt1 = item("CureDt1")
End Select
```

is there a way I can just do it (like in javascript)  where I would say  `oItemLabel[foo] = bar`

Comment: A little more context is required, such as the type of `oItemLabel`. You could do this using reflection, but you generally don't want to.

Comment: oItem label is an instance of a class.   so I am trying to say oItemLabel.someVariableHere = somevaluehere

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What you want to do using the syntax you show can be done if that class provides a string indexer.

Comment: not that I am familiar with it but I thought there was something called reflection that would allow this type of thing.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my former comment. See for example [C# setting/getting the class properties by string name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283206/c-sharp-setting-getting-the-class-properties-by-string-name) and [Can I set a property value with Reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718792/can-i-set-a-property-value-with-reflection).

Comment: Should this `oItemLabel.Shelf1 = item("value")` be `oItemLabel.Shelf1 = item("Shelf1")` ?

Comment: thanks codecaster your link worked well. I went with      Dim [property] = GetType(ItemLabel).GetProperty(item("itemLabelType"))
                [property].SetValue(oItemLabel, item("value"), Nothing).   Should I close this question as duplicate question since that link answered my question?